# With Next.js, my server freezes almost every time I fast reload or even run npm run dev

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js

I'm working on a project that freezes almost every time I fast reload or even run npm run dev. It used to be fine and work flawlessly until maybe a few weeks ago? When I say freeze, most of the elements on the page don't load, and my tab eventually says that the page has become unresponsive. I can't click on anything on the page or even right click to open dev tools, it's completely frozen. If I close the tab and open localhost on another tab, it usually works, up until I make a change and it hot reloads.

When I run npm run dev, I get green check marks all the way and no errors in regards to the compiling bit.

Unfortunately it happens with other projects I'm running next.js on as well, so I wonder if it's something with my system instead of the app files themselves.

I'm sure I'm missing something, but my initial thought is that because it happens on multiple next.js projects, it's with my system?

I'm running WSL 2 and Ubuntu 20.04.6, and recently updated Node to 18.19.0

3 things I've tried:

- updating node to the latest (I was getting warnings when I would run npm i that my current node version was unsupported)
  [Screenshot of the npm i error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaAuE.png). Unfortunately it didn't work.
- I saw somewhere that clearing my application cache in devtools would work, but I don't have the option to do so.
- Deleting the .next files in my directory and running npm run dev again to rebuild .next, but that doesn't work either.

edit: upon preliminary testing, it looks like firefox is working just fine with its local host. I typically work on Chrome however.